# Material-UI media query does't work with native styled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Wouldn't be possible to use **[props => props.theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]** ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { styled, withTheme } from '@material-ui/core';

export const DefaultContent = withTheme(
  styled(({ theme, ...other }) => <main {...other} />)({
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: props => props.theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    [props => props.theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need functions when using theme properties - it kind of looks like you're mixing backtick syntax (where you would see `props` passed in a function on each line) rather than object syntax. This works:

```
const DefaultContent = styled('main')(({ theme }) => ({
  flexGrow: 1,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  }
}));
```